# Javascript: array plus number

Tags: javascript

Some operations in javascript returns unexpected results. One is extremely strange:

```
[] + 1 = "1"
```

Can anybody explain why it works like that?

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 5):

`[]` are converted to an empty string due to + operator. so "" + 1 => "1" (number converted to string too)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's rules for addition between differeent types are as follows:

Given the following addition.

```
value1 + value2
```

To evaluate this expression, the following steps are taken (§11.6.1):
Convert both operands to primitives (mathematical notation, not JavaScript):

```
prim1 := ToPrimitive(value1)
prim2 := ToPrimitive(value2)
```

PreferredType is omitted and thus Number for non-dates, String for dates.
If either prim1 or prim2 is a string then convert both to strings and return the concatenation of the results.

Otherwise, convert both prim1 and prim2 to numbers and return the sum of the results.

[Source](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html)

In this case the array gets converted to an empty string, and then the + performs string concatenation

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript [11.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) defines addition. Steps 5 and 6 of addition call `ToPrimitive` ([9.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)) for each operand and operate on those results:

- For an array (or any object), `ToPrimative` calls the `toString` method of the object. The result of calling `toString` on an empty array is the empty string (per the behavior described in [15.4.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2).
- For a number, `ToPrimitive` returns the number (since numbers are already primitive).

We're left adding the empty string and the number 1. When either operand in addition is a string, the addition acts as a concatenation operation (per addition's step 7), so we end up with `"" + "1" = "1"`.