# Can anyone explain this Javascript anomaly with the Map function?

Tags: javascript

If I enter the following code into the JavaScript console, it returns the number 1310, but why?

```js
console.log(131+"".split(',').map(Number));
```

I'm adding `""` to `131` to convert it to a string, then using the `split` function to convert that string into an array, and the `map` function to make sure the values in the array are `Number`s.

I'm not sure where the 0 is coming from after the 131, can anyone explain this?

Comment: Check what `"".split(',')`  produces

Comment: _"I'm adding "" to 131 to convert it to a string, then using the split function to convert that string into an array"_ - no, you're not. You're using the `.split` method to convert `""` into an array. It's `131+("".split(',').map(Number));` not `(131+"").split(',').map(Number);` (which would give `[131]`) or (as I'd guess you actually wanted) `(131+"").split('').map(Number)` -> `[1, 3, 1]`.

Comment: Where do you expect the comma to come from?

Comment: This is a good example of why using `+` for string concatenation/conversion isn't ideal. I'd recommend using a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for most cases if your browser support allows it.

Comment: @DBS or just the old reliable `String(num)`

Comment: thanks for the explanation guys! 

@pointy in the current example theres no comma., but in the rest of my code commas will be added at a later date.

btw it seems a bit  strange that its mapping an empty string to the number 0   :/

Comment: Check out `String("".split(',').map(Number))` to see where the `0` comes from

Comment: It isn't mapping an empty string to the number 0. The call to `Number()` is doing that.

Comment: What  `Number(x)` results in is explained e.g. here [Number called using empty string, null, or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634614). `"".split(',')` results in `[""]`  and `[""].map(Number)` then results in `[0]`. And `131 + [0]`  is `131 + String([0])`

Comment: ah, thanks, that clears it up, cheers guys!

Comment: In addition to what I sayed in the other comment: [Javascript: array plus numbe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116507/javascript-array-plus-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member accessor `.` has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) than `+`

```js
const obj = { foo: 41 };

console.log( 1 + obj.foo );   // 42
console.log( 1 + (obj.foo) ); // 42
console.log( (1 + obj).foo ); // undefined
```

Thus in `131+"".split(',').map(Number)` the order of execution is (slightly abbreviated to focus on the important parts):

```
    131 + "".split(',') .map(Number)
//      ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
//      3       1             2
```

1. `"".split(',')` - split the empty string using a single comma. This results in `[ "" ]` (see [The confusion about the split() function of JavaScript with an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164883/the-confusion-about-the-split-function-of-javascript-with-an-empty-string)):

   ```js
   console.log( "".split(',') ); // [ "" ]
   ```
2. `[ "" ].map(Number)` - the `Number` function is applied to each member of the array. Since there the array after the split has a single empty string, it results in `[ 0 ]` because `Number("")` is `0` (see [Number called using empty string, null, or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634614/number-called-using-empty-string-null-or-undefined)):

   ```js
   console.log( Number("") );             // 0
   console.log( [ "" ].map(Number) ); // [ 0 ]
   ```
3. `131 + [ 0 ]` - adding a number and an array. This will first type coerce the array into a primitive then based on what kind of primitive it is (string or number) it will perform either numeric addition with `131` or string concatenation (coercing the other operand to a string first). Arrays convert to a string primitive by joining all members together (see [Why is [1,2] + [3,4] = "1,23,4" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-is-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript)). As the array only has a single member (a zero) the result is that single member as a string.

   ```js
   const result = 131 + [ 0 ];
   console.log(result, typeof result);                // 1310 string

   const arrayCoercion = "" + [ 0 ];
   console.log(arrayCoercion , typeof arrayCoercion); // 0 string
   ```

Therefore the code concatenates 131 and 0 together.

Answer (score 1):

To understand it better, break down of what the script you provided does:

```
console.log(131+"".split(',').map(Number));
```

Removing `console.log` makes following:

```
131+"".split(',').map(Number)
```

Evaluation happens firstly on `131`, then on `"".split(',').map(Number)`, essentially making it equivalent to

```
(131) + ("".split(',').map(Number))
```

`(131)` is just a number `131`. Looking at `"".split(',').map(Number)`, going from the leftmost:

```
"".split(',')
```

Will just return `['']`

```
[''].map(Number)
```

Will essentially be equivalent to

```
[ Number('') ]
```

Since `Number('')` is `0`, the result is `[0]`. Coming back:

```
(131) + ([0])
```

Is just `1310`. There you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `131 + "".split(",").map(Number)` you are adding `"".split(",").map(Number)` to `131`.
You need to use `(131 + "").split(",").map(Number)` for your expected outcome.

Comment: Though correct, this could be expanded upon. Why is the result `"1230"`? Where does the `"0"` come from?

Comment: @3limin4t0r this is explain in VLAZ answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78220432/9947331)